# getting current price bassed on effective date

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a query in SQL server 2008, that will look at a table of item pricing.  There are multiple records per item number and effective date for a pricing.

I need the query to scan down the table for each item number find the most recent date and return that pricing value in the results.

I am thinking I should use Max date and group by item number.

Suggestions of better ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `row_number()`

```
select *
from
(
     select 
          itemnumber, 
          price, 
          row_number() over (partition by itemnumber order by dateeffective desc) rn
     from prices
) effectiveprices
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly, and much easier than what I was about to try.